# Постановка запятой в вопросительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

скажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая в этом вопросительном предложении между двумя грамматическими основами?

Тебе приснился классный сон, и ты хочешь рассказать мне его?
или
Тебе приснился классный сон и ты хочешь рассказать мне его?

Answer (score 1):

В ССП союз ***и*** соединяет простые предложения, между которыми существуют причинно-следственные или условно-следственные отношения:

```
Раздался шелест травы, и из зарослей выскочил наш пес.

К обеду стало сухо в саду, и мы стали собирать опавшие яблоки.
```

Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/kakaya-chast-rechi/slovo-i-2.html

Без обобщающего слова эти предложения должна разделять запятая.